# Setting fixed context root of a Tapestry app deployed on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, tapestry, contextpath, contextroot

I was wondering if there is a way to make Tapestry application to always have the exact same context root when deployed on Glassfish server?

For example, I'd like to always access my app as `localhost:8080/myApp` instead of `localhost:8080/myApp-1.01-SNAPSHOT` or `localhost:8080/myApp-2.01-SNAPSHOT`.

I have made a `glassfish-web.xml` with the following property in there:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/admin</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

but it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, an oversight was done on my part. If I want Glassfish to use the context root I provided, I have to leave the `Context Root` field blank when deploying from web admin console.

Everything else is fine, including `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file.